# Tastypie - Queryset or filters

Tags: django, tastypie

Im using **tastypie** and i just ran into a problem.

My problem:

Users can post messages and if other users are subscribed to that user they can see those message on their homepage. Its **exactly like twitter** users tweeting and followers looking at their tweets.

I have a public api for all messages.
I can filter a particular users messages using `?userid=1`

**Bad solution to problem:**
I can filter multiple users messages (and thus solve the problem) using 
`?userid__in=1&userid__=5&...`

But this is not a good way because the url length is going to increase to a possibly unallowed amount. (2000 characters)

Is there a better way of doing this?
Is there a way I can use `request.user` in a **queryset** to do a join?
Or should I use some sort of **advanced filtering**?

Thank YOU!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tastypie already supports this via __in filtering (everything that ORM supports Tastypie exposes, except negations). No coding is necessary.

Look here: http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/v0.9.11/resources.html#basic-filtering

```
path/to/api/resource/?user_id__in=1,2,3,4,5,6
```

However, you can still have the problem of your URL becoming huge with someone subscribed to many users. What you can do instead is keep this information in the DB model (which user is subscribed to which user as a recursive ManyToMany relationship within the model through a separate joint model).

Then you could expose this through your resource without ever having to specify subscriptions through your URL as a parameter and/or filter. Instead your base queryset in the resource would be:

```
userids = request.user.subscription_userset.values(id)
```

provided that you have a `self` ManyToManyRelationship in your `User` model. Look [here](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/v0.9.11/fields.html#tastypie.fields.RelatedField.related_name), and [here](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/v0.9.11/fields.html#tomanyfield).

Answer (score 1):

What if you had someone pass in a list of `user_ids` they wanted to see updates for, and then filtered on that? Something like this:

`URL: your/api/messages.json?user_ids=5,8,10,25`

And then in the code you'd convert that into an actual list, and query:

`Message.objects.filter(user__id__in=user_ids)`

Comment: Thanks! Any idea how I can do this using tastypie?

Comment: No, but it looks like this will give you a good starting point: http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook.html#per-request-alterations-to-the-queryset